# How to specify USB port to a specific docker container?

Tags: android, docker, usb, appium

I'm trying to connect two different Android devices to two different docker containers. The guide from https://hub.docker.com/r/appium/appium says:

```
docker run -d -p 4723:4723 \
    --device /dev/bus/usb/XXX/YYY:/dev/bus/usb/XXX/YYY \
    -v ~/.android:/root/.android --name device1 appium/appium
```

XXX/YYY-> the 1st parameter is ok, it doesn't change, stable. The 2nd always different: after reboot/shut down/USB disconnect.

What is the proper way to separate devices in the docker?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

1. Copy the certificate to the container's volume. By this step phone is able to trust all new containers. And no need to reboot and reconnect the device.
2. XXX/YYY this parameters should be checked by *lsusb* utils. XXX is stable, in my case it always was 001. YYY changes by every connect/reboot, it increments by one. One should specify it like: 0001/014. and DO NOT DISCONNECT OR REBOOT.
3. In case of rebooting all the steps are needed to be made again. as YYY will be 015 and container wouldn't start.